# What's the difference checking if there is key in defaultdict?

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic, memoization

Suppose `house` is defaultdict.

```
house=defaultdict(int)
```

What's the difference between below two when writing Recursion Code with Memoization?

```
if house[i]:
...
```

and

```
if i in house:
...
```

I think the second one is the right way,
and when I tried with the first one, I got TLE(Time Limit Exceed) but I don't know why.
I want to know why the second one is correct.

Comment: The former may create the corresponding key value, and will be invalid when the corresponding value already exists but is 0.

Comment: There's not enough code shown here to help you with the TLE issue

Comment: MechanicPig's answer explains the two differences between `if i in house:` and `if house[i]:`. A third problem is that if one gets used to testing `if house[i]:` to test if `i` is in defaultdict `house`, then one will inevitably make mistakes the day when they encounter a defaultdict whose default value is not false, such as `defaultdict(lambda: 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The former has two problems: first is if the corresponding key does not exist, it will create a key value pair in the dictionary, and then return 0, which is valid in judgment:

```
>>> house = defaultdict(int)
>>> if house[0]: print('hello')
...
>>> house
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {0: 0})
```

The second problem is that if the key already exists, but the corresponding value is 0 or other value which truth value is false, the judgment will be wrong:

```
>>> house[1] = 0
>>> if house[1]: print('hello')
...
>>>
```